# Intertemporal profit maximization

Tags: producer-theory, dynamic-optimization, intertemporal-choice

Assume a producer wishes to maximize the net present value, choosing optimal quantities of K and L. variables are time dependent. y is the production function, p is the price of y. K is capital, r is the price of capital, L is labor, w is wage.

$$ \max_{K(t), L(t)} \pi(t)= \int_{t=0}^T (p(t) . y(t) - [r(t).K(t) + w(t).L(t)]).e^{-\rho.t} .dt
$$
Subject to the constraint:
$$ S.t: y(t) = K(t)^a . L(t)^b $$

Can I have some guidance on how to solve this optimization problem? Do I simply need to set up the lagrangian? Derive it with respect to K and L? I don't think I need to use the Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 0):

This is an intertemporal dynamic problem, but the fact that the restriction contains no derivatives allows us to solve it using a static optimization approach. Replacing the constraint into the objective:
$$
\pi(t) = \int_0^T \Big[ p(t)K(t)^{a}L(t)^{b} - r(t)K(t) - w(t)L(t) \Big]e^{-\rho t} dt
$$

The fact that there are no derivatives in the constraint means that what the agent does in one instant $t$ of time, does not affect the future. This is why we can simply differentiate with respect to the instruments, $L(t)$ and $K(t)$.

$$ \frac{d\pi(t)}{dL(t)} = \int_0^T \Big[ bp(t)K(t)^{a}L(t)^{b-1}-w(t) \Big]e^{-\rho t} dt =0 $$

$$ \frac{d\pi(t)}{dK(t)} = \int_0^T \Big[ap(t)K(t)^{a-1}L(t)^{b}-r(t)\Big]e^{-\rho t} dt =0 $$

These are the FOC of the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much.